# Hadoop simple Java program - Interaction with MongoDB

Tags: hadoop

I have chosen Hadoop for dataprocessing, and i use MongoDB for storage in one of my 
project which includes much data.

I configured and installed hadoop and executed the sample given in [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/), which has example to 
read number of occurences of words in given text documents and its working fine.

But when i try to look out for a simple Java example which would connect to MongoDB and do a simple
data processng like number of records stored in a table belong to some simple criteria (`name like '%John%'`)

Do any one have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at these links 1. http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/hadoop/ 2. http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB%2BHadoop+Connector.html If these doesn't help let me know. I will try and post a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an working sample.

I followed the steps to implement example UFO sightings in [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/) and its working just like that.

Note : Make sure to install mongodb first, or else you may face errors when loading sample data.
Follow [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) for steps to install mongodb.